# Why does a callable function output a closure object in this instance?

Tags: php, function, oop, closures, callable

The way I undestand it, `callable` is just a typehint, and we pass it via a function/method parameters to enforce whatever passed after it should be a type`callable` (in otherwords a function) see this example:

```
function foo(\Callable $fn){
     var_dump($fn); 
}
```

so I am assuming `$fn` should be a function, so I pass it a function as

```
$fn = function(){

};

foo($fn);
```

And  I get the output

```
object(Closure)#1 (0) {
}
```

This is what I don't understand, where does the `object` and `closure` come from?

Comment: Anonymous functions are maintained in PHP as an object of type closure, that's just how it works. Beyond that I'm not sure what the question is. Have a read of http://php.net/closures if you haven't already.

Comment: I guess I am trying to understand the relationship between `Callable` and both closure and anonymouse functions

Comment: please refer to **[the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)**, which quite clearly states *what and what not is callable*. especially see example #2, named "Callback example using a Closure".